# calculate the weekday information based on date information

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In a dataframe created using Pandas, there is one column, i.e., 'date', storing the value of date, i.e., 2012-10-8, how can I create another column, each entry of which stores the weekdays for the corresponding date entry.

In other words, I would like to have two columns

```
date         weekday
2012-10-8    Tuesday
```

The weekday entry need to be computed based on the date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html).

```
df.date.dt.day_name()

0    Monday
Name: date, dtype: object
```

While not necessary here, it also takes `locale` as a parameter

```
df.date.dt.day_name(locale='es')

0    Lunes
Name: date, dtype: object
```

---

[`pandas.Series.dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) is new in `pandas 0.23.0`, if you are using a previous version, use `weekday_name` instead:

```
df.date.dt.weekday_name

0    Monday
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Using `weekday_name` has been [deprecated in `0.23.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.weekday_name.html) in favor of `day_name()`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `.dt` accessor and `strftime` using `%A`

```
>>> df.date.dt.strftime('%A')

0    Monday
Name: date, dtype: object
```

ps: Note that `2012-10-08` was a *Monday*, and not *Tuesday*